# Check the date is past?

Tags: php, html

```
$expire_dt = "2016-11-01 01:08:00";
$today_dt = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');

if ($expire_dt < $today_dt)
{
    echo "AVAILABLE";
}
else
{
    echo"EXPIRED";
}
```

This code always shows EXPIRED. I wanna show the date is expired or not.

Comment: And why is the mysql and html tags.?

Comment: We are in the year 2013. In 3 years you will get "available".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [The DateTime class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-create.php)

```
<?php
  $expire_dt = date_create('2016-11-01 01:08:00');
  $today_dt = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
  if($expire_dt > $today_dt){
     //do something
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Compare integer representations of dates by using [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and [time](https://www.php.net/time).

```
$expire_dt = strtotime("2016-11-01 01:08:00");
$today_dt = time();
```

Answer (score 0):

You try to compare a string and a date. You should construct a date from the string  before the comparison. You can do that by using [date_parse](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse.php) for instance.